Index cleanup vaccum
Seems its asking again,but with some tets have done but unable to get on below things-
VACUUM INDEX_CLEANUP { AUTO | ON | OFF }

Where this parameter should be enabled,like at the database level or table level or index level?.

Do I need to disable anything inorder to run above option?

I have simulated bloat that not working at all  to see what difference to measure here?


can someone please help Me to what benefit we will get and when we need to use this explictly.
CREATE TABLE demo_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data TEXT
);

INSERT INTO demo_table (data)
SELECT 'Some test data ' || generate_series(1, 10000000);

CREATE INDEX idx_demo_table_data ON demo_table (data);

UPDATE demo_table SET data = 'Updated test data' WHERE id % 2 = 0;


VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) demo_table;

-- Before vacuum
SELECT 
    indexrelname AS index_name, 
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) AS index_size, 
    idx_scan AS index_scans, 
    idx_tup_read AS tuples_read, 
    idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes WHERE indexrelname = 'idx_demo_table_data';

-- After vacuum
SELECT 
    indexrelname AS index_name, 
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) AS index_size, 
    idx_scan AS index_scans, 
    idx_tup_read AS tuples_read, 
    idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes WHERE indexrelname = 'idx_demo_table_data';

- After vacuum
SELECT 
    indexrelname AS index_name, 
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) AS index_size, 
    idx_scan AS index_scans, 
    idx_tup_read AS tuples_read, 
    idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes WHERE indexrelname = 'idx_demo_table_data';


VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, INDEX_CLEANUP=ON) demo_table;                --its not working at all

-- Before vacuum
SELECT 
    indexrelname AS index_name, 
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) AS index_size, 
    idx_scan AS index_scans, 
    idx_tup_read AS tuples_read, 
    idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes WHERE indexrelname = 'idx_demo_table_data';

-- After vacuum
SELECT 
    indexrelname AS index_name, 
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) AS index_size, 
    idx_scan AS index_scans, 
    idx_tup_read AS tuples_read, 
    idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes WHERE indexrelname = 'idx_demo_table_data';


Add to your question as text: 1) Postgres version. 2) The results from your queries.

Postgresql is 15, before vaccum-index_name      | index_size | index_scans | tuples_read | tuples_fetched
---------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------------
idx_demo_table_data | 418 MB     |           0 |           0 |              0

aafter  vaccum VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) demo_table;
INFO:  vacuuming "indtest.public.demo_table"
INFO:  launched 1 parallel vacuum worker for index vacuuming (planned: 1)
INFO:  finished vacuuming "indtest.public.demo_table": index scans: 1
pages: 0 removed, 105367 remain, 73521 scanned (69.78% of total)

index "demo_table_pkey": pages: 54839 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
index "idx_demo_table_data": pages: 53561 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
INFO:  vacuuming "indtest.pg_toast.pg_toast_33482"
INFO:  finished vacuuming "indtest.pg_toast.pg_toast_33482": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 0 remain, 0 scanned (100.00% of total)
tuples: 0 removed, 0 remain, 0 are dead but not yet removable
removable cutoff: 973, which was 0 XIDs old when operation ended
new relfrozenxid: 973, which is 5 XIDs ahead of previous value

index scan not needed: 0 pages from table (100.00% of total) had 0 dead item identifiers removed
INFO:  analyzing "public.demo_table"
INFO:  "demo_table": scanned 30000 of 105367 pages, containing 2859693 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 10043909 estimated total rows

indtest=# SELECT
indtest-#     indexrelname AS index_name,
indtest-#     pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) AS index_size,
indtest-#     idx_scan AS index_scans,
indtest-#     idx_tup_read AS tuples_read,
indtest-#     idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
indtest-# FROM pg_stat_user_indexes WHERE indexrelname = 'idx_demo_table_data';
index_name      | index_size | index_scans | tuples_read | tuples_fetched
---------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------------
idx_demo_table_data | 418 MB     |           0 |           0 |              0
(1 row)

Really? Read my first comment, especially this Add to your question as text:.

sincere apologize..not sure where this should be get add,Iam not getting.

Add the information in properly formatted form to the text of your original question,

This VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, INDEX_CLEANUP=ON) demo_table; needs to be VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, INDEX_CLEANUP ON) demo_table; otherwise the command fails.

You realize a regular VACUUM will clean up the table indexes. Using your example and vacuuming after the update in VACUUM output I get among other things: index scan needed: 64102 pages from table (60.84% of total) had 4999956 dead item identifiers removed ... index "idx_demo_table_data": pages: 40085 in total, 7654 newly deleted, 7654 currently deleted, 0 reusable

I think I see what is going on, the on disk size of the index is not shrinking. See this post Index space growing even after cleanup via autovacuum for reason why. Basically if you really need to shrink the index you will need to REINDEX, otherwise just let the index recycle the old pages.

Please edit the question and make it clear. As it is, I don't know if you have trouble with the syntax of VACUUM or if you have trouble measuring the effects of the statement. And I don't want the clarification in a comment. The question must be clear without having to read through a bunch of comments.

yes understood,since Iam new still need to go through and will do for sure.. My question is VACUUM INDEX_CLEANUP { AUTO | ON | OFF }
Where this parameter should be enabled,like at the database level or table level or index level?.
Do I need to disable anything inorder to run above option?
I have simulated bloat that not working at all to see what difference to measure here?
can someone please help Me to what benefit we will get and when we need to use this explictly.  Also I want to simulate the tests to see its working and reclaim space for index getting either reused or left os

Since you seem incapable of following instructions or reading the information already provided that answers your questions there is not really anything more that can be said or done.

Hi Adrian, gone through it ,will do couple of tests on that and will see... ..In simple way..I want something to demonstrate the scenarios by keeping the option for INDEX_CLEANUP=ON for Vaccum..  purpose of Index cleanup when to use and in what situation..n how to simulate in local machines to understand much better way..
